# My react project is showing white blank screen with the use of api to get data from the back in react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api

I have already done the back and front of the project but when I am trying to get a data from the back with the use of useFetch, it shows me white blank space.

I have tried all my best to get data from the back through the use of the api but it just showing me blank. When I remove the useFetch method, everything works well.

```
useFetch.js
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios";

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState([false])
    const [error, setError] = useState([false])

    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchData = async ()=>{
            setLoading(true)
            try{
                const res = await axios.get(url);
                setData(res.data);
            }catch(err){
                setError(err)
            }
            setLoading(false)
        };
        fetchData();

    },[url])

    const reFetch = async ()=>{
        setLoading(true)
        try{
            const res = await axios.get(url);
            setData(res.data);
        }catch(err){
            setError(err)
        }
        setLoading(false)
    };

    return { data, loading, error, reFetch}

};

export default useFetch;
```

featured.js

```
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";
import "./featured.css";

const Featured = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } =  useFetch(
    "/hotels/countByCity?cities=freetown,makeni,bo"
  );

  return (
    <div className="featured">
      
          <div className="featuredItem">
        <img
          src="https://tourismsierraleone.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Freetown2.jpg"
          alt=""
          className="featuredImg"
        />
        <div className="featuredTitles">
          <h1>Freetown</h1>
          <h2>20 properties</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div className="featuredItem">
        <img
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Makeni_Wusum.JPG"
          alt=""
          className="featuredImg"
        />
        <div className="featuredTitles">
          <h1>Makeni</h1>
          <h2>50 properties</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="featuredItem">
        <img
          src="https://www.visitsierraleone.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/doha-1.jpg"
          alt=""
          className="featuredImg"
        />
        <div className="featuredTitles">
          <h1>Bo</h1>
          <h2>35 properties</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Featured;
```

Comment: why are you putting **url** as a dependency to `useEffect` . it should be empty if you want it to run in the first render. and change `useState([false])` to `useState(false)`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
const [data, setData] = useState()
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
const [error, setError] = useState(false)

useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async ()=>{
        setLoading(true)
        try{
            const res = await axios.get(url);
            setData(res.data);
        }catch(err){
            setError(err)
        }
        setLoading(false)
    };
    fetchData().catch(err => setError(err));
},[url])
```

useState here are not supposed to be an array of boolean, you just want to know if you're data are loading or not and if you catch an error.

Can you also check your api url ?